# Как можно представить список функций с разными результатами и вызвать их?

Tags: c++

У меня есть известный на этапе компиляции список функций, **возвращающих разные типы** (но принимающих одинаковые). Как можно представить такой гетерогенный список, чтобы потом проитерироваться по нему и получить список значений (например, в tuple)?

```cpp
int foo();
double bar();
constexpr auto functions = {foo, bar, foo, bar};
auto results;
for (function: functions) {
  results.push_back(function());
}
// results is equivalent to std::tuple{foo(), bar(), foo(), bar()}
```

Comment: И как вы себе представляете потом работу с таким вектором разнотипных значений? Конечно, можно воспользоваться типом `vector<std::any>`, но смысл? Для чего это вам нужно? Написание очередного калькулятора? :) Может, лучше спросить, как забить гвоздь, чем выяснять, в какой руке держать микроскоп, забивая им гвозди? :) О, вы поменяли вопрос... тогда просто используйте [`make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple). Это вам подходит?

Comment: @Harry мне не надо потом с ним серьёзно работать, только распаковать этот тапл по переменным. Но чтобы уменьшить дупликацию кода пришёл к такой к идее. Изначальная задача: есть файл с значениями разных типов в определённых местах, который надо распарсить в переменные. Т.е. например в 1 и 3 строке у нас A, а в 2 и 4 - B, для A и B есть свои функции чтения. Но просто сделать in >> a >> b >> a >> b нельзя, т.к. между ними надо ещё выполнить проверки, зависящие от итерации. Поэтому придумал {>>A, >>B, >>A, >>B} и в цикле вызывать эту проверку вместо повторений in >> a; check(0); in >> b; check(1)

Comment: @Harry допустим, я сделаю тапл функций, но как потом по нему проитерироваться с применением?

Comment: *допустим, я сделаю тапл функций, но как потом по нему проитерироваться с применением?* — а это вы скажите :), я о том и писал в самом начале, что мне этот проект представляется нерабочим. Итак, ваша задача: файл со значениями в строках, который надо прочитать и расписать по переменным. Каким? Файл имеет четкую структуру или нет? Как выбираются переменные? и еще 1001 вопрос по точной формулировке задания... Без этого имеем разговоры ни о чем...

Comment: @Harry неизменная структура, например, A, B, A, B сериализованные. И есть функция для чтения A и фунция для чтения B. Но между чтениями надо делать постороннюю работу, зависящую от итерации, допустим лог того, что прочитали i-ую строку. Я могу написать `foo(); log(0); bar(); log(1); foo(); log(2); bar(); log(3)`. Но вместо этого хочу `for (int i; i < functions.size(); ++i) { functions[i](); log(i); }` И чтобы результаты в тапле в итоге были или любом другом контейнере, чтобы можно было распаковать типа `auto [a1, b1, a2, b2] = results;`

Comment: Ну, смысла распаковывать контейнер с неизвестным (или большим) количеством не вижу, что до обработки - ну просто чередуйте вызовы типа `for(int i = 0; ...) { i%2 ? bar() : foo(); log(i); }` Разнородные значения придется складывать в `any`, или заранее заготовить tuple с нужными параметрами... а вы их знаете заранее?... Ладно, все это разговоры ни о чем... :(

Comment: Представить как `std::tuple`, а для получения результатов внутрь `std::make_tuple(...)` запихнуть https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136761.